# Function Call Operator Precedence

Tags: python, function, parsing, expression

According to [this site](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html) function calls take precedence over attribute access which has got me confused.

```
>>> class cls:
    def func(self):
        print("Method")


>>> def func():
    print("Global Func")


>>> obj=cls() 
>>> obj.func() #1
Method
>>> (obj.func)() #2
Method
>>> obj.(func()) #3
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

3 was an expected syntax error but why does 1 and 2 produce the same thing if function calls take precedence over attribute access?

Comment: What were you expecting that was different?  I don't see how precedence comes into play here.

Comment: I would expect obj.func() to produce an error since it would produce obj.None after func() was evaluated

Comment: @ColinHicks attribute names must be strings FWIW, so it would be nonsensical for Python to do that. (Of course, I understand you know that and is why you expect it to be an error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That website is slightly wrong according to the official Python documentation that it links to: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

You'll notice that the operator precedence listed by Python's documentation has, in the second to last slot in the table, all on the same line: `x[index]`, `x[index:index]`, `x(arguments...)`, `x.attribute`. And as the docs state,

> Operators in the same box have the same precedence. ... Operators in the same box group left to right (except for exponentiation, which groups from right to left).

The site you linked to states the same, only puts those four things in an order, instead of in the same box, for whatever reason.